# How do I use awk to only grab "name_of_package.rpm?"

Tags: awk, yum

I'm trying to grab only "name_of_package.rpm" from a list of 10,000+ packages available for CentOS 7. I've tried various iterations/combinations of awk and grep with no avail. I've tried using Google and a few ideas from other questions asked here, but nothing seems to work for me at the moment. Any assistance is appreciated!

```
awk -F '\w' '{print $2}' /data/rpm-list
cat /data/rpm-list | grep -o "\w*\.rpm\w*"\
cat /data/rpm-list | grep -o "*\.rpm"
```

This is what I'm trying to parse through:

```
[   ]   389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64.rpm   2018-11-12 14:21    1.7M     
[   ]   389-ds-base-devel-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64.rpm 2018-11-12 14:21    271K     
[   ]   389-ds-base-libs-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64.rpm  2018-11-12 14:21    698K     
[   ]   389-ds-base-snmp-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64.rpm  2018-11-12 14:21    167K
```

I just wanted the "name_of_package.rpm" without the "[ ]", dates, or sizes. I fully intend to pass this list through a script that will download everything with its dependencies to a personal lab server that I can use offline. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your shown sample input looks like you could simply do(again fully based on your shown sample Input_file).

```
awk '{print $3}'  Input_file
```

---

***EDIT:*** In case you are more interested to know about field numbers with their field values then you could run following command too.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print "Field number is: "i " Field value is: "$i}}' Input_file
```

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out why it wasn't considered the second field. Logically it made sense to do $2 by looking at it. Guess I wasn't taking the white space into account. Thank you!

Comment: @Nick, you could select it as a correct answer too, I will add some explanation for fields understanding too in few mins.